# I don't understand why Angulajs filter is not working as expected?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I have a AngularJS filter based on four user inputs. Two inputs, Category and Author, come from drop down lists. One input come from text input and other one come from radio group. I use a button to clear user inputs.

No filtered data is displayed as I enter desired values in respective inputs. Instead filtered data is displayed when I click button to clear fed in values.

I can't understand where and what I am doing wrong as I am new to AngularJS.

## Filter.js

```
angular.module("customFilters", [])
.filter("unique", function() {
    return function(data, propertyName) {
        if (angular.isArray(data) && angular.isString(propertyName)) {
            var results = [];
            var keys = {};
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var val = data[i][propertyName];
                if (angular.isUndefined(keys[val])) {
                    keys[val] = true;
                    results.push(val);
                }
            }
            return results;
        } else {
            return data;
        }
    }
})
```

## Controller.js

```
App
.controller('PadaListController', function($scope, $state, PagerService) {
    
    // Private Data
    var selectedCategory = null;
    var selectedAuthor = null;


    // Assigns user selected Category to private variable selectedCategory
    $scope.selectCategory = function(newCategory) {
        selectedCategory = newCategory;
    }
    
    // Filter padas by selected Category
    $scope.categoryFilterFn = function(pada) {
        return selectedCategory == null || 
            pada.category == selectedCategory;
    }

    // Assigns user selected Author to private variable selectedAuthor
    $scope.selectAuthor = function(newAuthor) {
        selectedAuthor = newAuthor;
    }

    // Filter padas by selected Author
    $scope.authorFilterFn = function(pada) {
        return selectedAuthor == null || 
            pada.author == selectedAuthor;
    }
});
```

## list.html

```
<md-content>
<md-card md-theme="{{ appDefaults.showDarkTheme ? 'dark-blue' : 
appDefaults.theme || 'default' }}">
    <button type="button" ng- 
    click="catgry='';authr='';search='';direction=''">Clear 
    Filters</button>

    <md-card-header layout ng-click="showSearch=!showSearch">
        <md-card-avatar class="md-user-avatar">
            <md-icon md-svg-src="img/material/baseline-search-24px.svg"> 
            </md-icon>
        </md-card-avatar>
        <md-card-header-text>
            <div class="md-headline">Search</div>
            <div class="md-subhead">and Order</div>
        </md-card-header-text>
    </md-card-header>

    <!-- Card contents -->
    <div ng-show="showSearch">
        <md-card-content>
                 
            <label arial-label="category">Select Category</label>
            <md-select ng-model="catgry" ng- 
            change="selectCategory(catgry)">
                <md-option>None</md-option>
                <md-option value={{catgry}} 
                    ng-repeat="catgry in data.padas | orderBy:'category' | 
                    unique: 'category'">
                    {{catgry}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>

            <label aria-label="author">Select Author</label>
            <md-select ng-model="authr" ng-change="selectAuthor(authr)">
                <md-option value={{authr}} 
                ng-repeat="authr in data.padas | orderBy:'author' | 
                unique: 'author'">
                    {{authr}}
                </md-option>
            </md-select>
            
            <md-input-container>
                <label aria-label="pada search">Search/Goto</label>
                <input type="text" ng-model="search" />   
            </md-input-container>

            <md-radio-group ng-model="direction">
                <md-radio-button value="" aria-label="आरोही क्रम"> 
                    Ascending</md-radio-button>    
                <md-radio-button value="reverse" aria-label="अवरोही 
                    क्रम">Descending</md-radio-button>
            </md-radio-group>
    
        </md-card-content>
    </div>
</md-card>

<md-card
    ng-repeat="pada in (filteredPadas = (data.padas | 
    filter:categoryFilterFn | filter:authorFilterFn | filter:search | 
    orderBy:direction))" ng-click="showPadaDetails=!showPadaDetails">
        <!-- Filtered Contents -->
</md-card>
</md-content>
```

I want to show filtered data as i feed in values in respective inputs fields and when I click clear filter button entire data should be displayed.

Comment: How does your data look like? I mean give me an example for values of **$scope.data**

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you have space in **"ng-click"** after the **ng-** part like this **"ng- click"**, and the same problem is for **ng-change**
remove white spaces and make it connected as one word, let me know if that helped you.

Another thing I noticed

inside `ng-repeat="catgry in data.padas | orderBy:'category' | unique: 'category'"`

You should show content of **data.padas object** so instead of

```
{{catgry}}
```

it should be

```
{{catgry.category}}
```

same for `ng-repeat="authr in data.padas | orderBy:'author' | unique: 'author'"`

instead of

```
{{authr}}
```

it should be

```
{{authr.author}}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to investigate the problem and reply thereof. I am sorry to say that the cause(space) you pointed out is not valid. I checked my code. The space might have got inserted while I was reformatting the code on this site to post my question. I request you to have a look at the problem once again...

Comment: $scope.data.padas is an array of objects which look like as follows:

Comment: $scope.data.padas is an array of objects which looks like as follows: data.padas = [ {
  "padaID":  1,
  "pageNo": "11",
  "gorelalPg": "1",
  "padaSankhya": "॥ पद ॥ १ ॥",
  "title":  "प्रथम लड़ाऊँ श्री गुरु",
  "name":   "मंगलाचरन",
  "category":  "मंगलाचरन",
  "author":  "श्रीस्वामी कृष्णदास जू",
  "raag":   "सूहौ बिलावल",
  "taal":   "रूपक (सात मात्रा)",
  "lyrics": [
   "प्रथम लड़ाऊँ श्री गुरु, बंदन करि श्रीहरिदास ।",
   "विपुल प्रेम निजु नेम गहि, कहि सुजस बिहारिनदास ॥१॥"
  ]
 }, ...]. This array has 787 objects. This one is has shortest lyrics property.

Comment: Did you pay attention on **unique** filter which returns array of unique property passed to it. In this case i am passing **category** and **author** properties and getting arrays in return.

Comment: That is why **catgry.category** and **authr.author** are not possible as **catgry** and **authr** are not objects rather they are strings. Please correct me if I am taking things wrong. All code is working fine but except filter is not getting cleared, that is all.